# Python FuelSDK - feed a list to search_filter?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

Is there a way to feed a list of values to an ET object search_filter so that it will match on any of the strings in the list?

```
email_list = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com']
getSubscriber = ET_Client.ET_Subscriber()
getSubscriber.auth_stub = stubObj
getSubscriber.props = ["ID","SubscriberKey"]
getSubscriber.search_filter = {'Property' : 'SubscriberKey','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : email_list}
```

I tried this and it did not pull anything. Is something like this possible with FuelSDK search_filter?

Comment: Have you tired looping it? You

Comment: I considered doing that, but wouldn't that eat up a lot of API calls if I was using a large list?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'IN' instead of 'equals'

getSubscriber.search_filter = {'Property' : 'SubscriberKey','SimpleOperator' : 'IN','Value' : email_list}